# Crashes in autorelease (cocos2d)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have class TileMap. It initialization I load the level in memory and reads the width and height. But when I call this class with autorelease -> program crashes

in .h

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface TileMap : NSObject
{
    CCTMXTiledMap *_tileMap;
    float _width, _height;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCTMXTiledMap *tileMap;
@property (readwrite) float width;
@property (readwrite) float height;

-(void) loadMapWithLVL : (NSString *)lvl;
@end
```

in .m

```
#import "TileMap.h"

@implementation TileMap

@synthesize tileMap = _tileMap;
@synthesize width = _width;
@synthesize height = _height;

- (void) dealloc
{
    //[_tileMap release];
    self.tileMap = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) loadMapWithLVL: (NSString *)lvl
{
    [self.tileMap release];
    NSString *lvl_new = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.tmx",lvl];

    CCLOG(@"Reload TileMap to %@", lvl_new);
    self.tileMap = [[CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:lvl_new] retain];
    self.width = _tileMap.mapSize.width;
    self.height = _tileMap.mapSize.height;    
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        CCLOG(@"Init TileMap");
        self.tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"1lvl.tmx"];
        self.width = _tileMap.mapSize.width;
        self.height = _tileMap.mapSize.height;
        CCLOG(@"size map in init %0.2f %0.2f", _width, _height);

    }        
    return self;
}    
@end
```

in another class when I write:

```
    TileMap *testmap = [[[TileMap alloc] init] autorelease];
    float testg = testmap.width;
    CCLOG(@"size map %0.2f", testg);
```

I have crash. But when I write:

```
TileMap *testmap = [[TileMap alloc] init];
float testg = testmap.width;
CCLOG(@"size map %0.2f", testg);
[testmap release]
```

I have not crash. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code. At first, you declared property as 'retain' -     `@property (nonatomic, retain) CCTMXTiledMap *tileMap;` and 'synthesize' it as well. It means that now you can operate with this property without any release/retain keyword. So rewrite method `loadMapWithLVL` like this:

```
-(void) loadMapWithLVL: (NSString *)lvl{
    NSString *lvl_new = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.tmx",lvl];

    CCLOG(@"Reload TileMap to %@", lvl_new);
    self.tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:lvl_new];
    self.width = _tileMap.mapSize.width;
    self.height = _tileMap.mapSize.height;    
}
```

One more thing - Don't call `self.` in `dealloc` method when you clean properties. `[_tileMap release];, _titleMap = nil;` is a correct approach for cleaning memory.